# Photos on the members profile

Tags: civireport

Can you please let me know how can I add photos on the member's profiles? I can not find it in the database.

Comment: That's great! Pleased you could find it. If my response below is correct, could you accept it as such? It will help others and mark this question as having an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're asking how to add the contact image field to a CiviCRM profile?

As that field exists for all contact type, you need to select "Contact" first. The field is then called "Image Url"

This will upload an image onto the contact's record.

[image]